# Writing content in cells of excel using excel object is viewed in c#.net

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am going to write the content to the cells of an excel template using excel object in c#.net.

I have no problem in writing in the cells of the excel it works fine, but while writing the content in the cells of the excel, i can able to view the content writing in the cells.

But I need to restrict not view this action.

Can any one give me an idea about how to resolve this issue?

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are expecting?can you show us the code where you are writing this content

Comment: You could just make the `ExcelApplication` not visible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to hide screen updating, try:

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

At the end, don't forget to turn it back on:

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096090/fastest-way-to-write-cells-to-excel-with-office-interop) may help as well.